# Loading a Windows registry hive with Ruby

Tags: ruby, registry

Does Ruby have a way to load a Registry hive? I want to load a logged out user's hive for modification. I was not able to find the appropriate method in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/dl/rdoc/Win32/Registry.html). I am very new to Ruby so I may have simply missed the method.

I know it's possible with `reg load <key> <file>` but doing that would be more of a work around.